# Is barley the same as bulgur?

Tags: grains, barley

Some sources seem to suggest that they are not, some suggest that they are *but* they are treated/processed differently.

I want to know if they are fundamentally the same grain, because they are very similar when prepared.

For reference:

### Whole bulgur:

[image]

### Whole (pearled) barley:

[image]

Comment: Where did your picture fit "whole bulgur" come from? Bulge by definition isn't whole

Comment: Please, supply sources. And no, they are not the same.

Comment: @ChrisH:  The picture appears to be from a California grain distributor, sold as ["whole-kernel organic bulgur."](http://sunnylandmills.com/portfolio-items/whole-kernel-organic-bulgur/)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I'm not familiar witht he US, but in the bits of Europe, I know "whole kernel bulgur" is a contradiction.  The usage at Wikipedia (link in my answer) matches what I'm familiar with, so I wonder if the question has a hint of "what's this strange bulgur?" about it

Comment: There are very high quality a wikipedia pages on barley and bulgur. What kind of research have you done to answer your question?

Comment: @ChrisH:  I'm from the US, and I had never heard of "whole-kernel bulgur" before reading this question either.

Comment: Yeah, your first photo isn't bulgur, no matter how the merchant labelled it.

Comment: There's some flour mills here on the West Coast with the irritating practice of labeling cracked wheat as "bulgur".  Bob's Red Mill does this as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. Bulgur is [(almost always) made from wheat](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulgur) while barley is a different species.

Bulgur is cracked and parboiled before sale, while pearl barley has had the outer layers of the barley grain removed but is otherwise intact.

Comment: Pedantic nitpick: Bulgar is parboiled and then cracked. If cracked first it would have enough liberated starch to make a porridge when parboiled instead. I only mention this in case someone wants to make it at home.

Comment: Bulgur is wheat, genus *Triticum*. There are several other forms of the same plant, such as Farro, Kamut. Spelt is also a cultivar of wheat. Barley is genus *Hordeum*. Note that Buckwheat is not wheat either: it is genus *Fagopyrum*.